# Control of parallel foreach flow

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have to run two tasks using `Parallel.ForEach` but I want the first to finish and *then* start the second.

```
Parallel.Foreach(items, (item, state) =>
{
    Task1(item);
    Task2(item);
}
public void Task1(Item item)
{
    var records = GetRecordsToExport();
    UpdateFields1(records);
}
public void Task2(Item item)
{
    var content = File.Read(...);
    // read every line in content, and for every line update field DB
    foreach(var c in content)
    {
        UpdateFields2(c); // different methods
    }
}
```

This is the code, I can't post more as the code is pretty big

`Task1` checks for some records into the DB that need updates and `Task2` checks for the last updated records (those from Task1) and updates them again.

Initially I had the tasks the other way around and couldn't find out why program was crashing. This is because one task started before other one finished, and they operate on the same DB tables.
How can I control the order of running?

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense.  `Task1` and `Task2` will not run at the same time for the same `item`.  As you have written it, `Task2` will always run after `Task1`, exactly as you would expect to make sense.  The most likely problem is that the code inside `Task1` and `Task2` is not threadsafe.  Using `Parallel.ForEach` you will have *many* `Task1`s and `Task2`s running at the same time, each however running for a different `item`.  You should show us the code for `Task1` and `Task2`.

Comment: Well, what are you saying is not true. Task1 checks for some records into DB that needs to be updated, and Task2 checks for the last updated records and updates them again. The problem arised when both task1 and task2 operated on the same record, and that happened on task1 almost finished and task2 started. I need multiple tasks to run in background, like all task1, and then all task2...but without a foreach for every task.

Comment: Are you spinning a new thread for `Task1` and `Task2` internally? Please add the code for both of them.

Comment: `Task2` is updating the **Last Updated Record**? but you want to update multiple records simultaneously?

Comment: "I have to run two tasks using Parallel.ForEach but I want the first to finish and then start the second." => Use Task1.ContinueWith(Task2)?

Comment: So you want something like `Parallel.Foreach(items, (item, state) =>
{
    Task1(item);
} Parallel.Foreach(items, (item, state) =>
{
    Task2(item);
}`

Comment: Task2 is not necessarly updating the last updated record, but it can happen. Task 1 is the export process and task 2 is the import process. The order is first export, and then import. I want the export to be finished so that and only after that import can be started, as it makes no sense to import data if exported is not finished. I want the same thing with 2 foreachs, but I don't want to write code like that. For every item, I need this order: export->import. I don't need all exports (task1) to be finished, just per item I need export before import (task 1 before task2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is block the access to Task2, while there is any thread running in Task1. And the other way around, no thread is allowed to enter Task1, when any Task2 is still running.

I think you can try to use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();


Parallel.Foreach(items, (item, state) =>
{
    lock.EnterReadLock();
    try {
        Task1(item);
    } finally {
        lock.ExitReadLock()
    }
    lock.EnterWriteLock();
    try {
        Task2(item);
    } finally {
        lock.ExitWriteLock()
    }
}
```

This code will also prevent any Task2 methods to be entered twice. If you need that, you can try to use Semaphore or Mutex. But this will make it more complicated.

Comment: Doing such thing it seems that Parallel loop won't make any difference. If you will hold other threads until a task is performed, there won't be parallel execution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Will these work AS export1, export2, ..., exportN and then import1, import2, ..., importN OR AS export1, import1, ..., exportN, importN ? Because I need the second. If it is the second, then this is the code I needed. (export is task1 and import is task2)

Comment: Task1 will still be performed parallel. And it seems he has a problem with executing Task1 and Task2 at the same time.

Comment: @raresm: This will be the first case, first all importN (not in order, executed in parallel) and then ExportN (not in order, executed not in parallel).

Comment: I assume you meant exportN and then importN, as export is task1 and import is task2. This was the answer I need, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible for Task2 to operate on a an item that Task1 hasn't completed processing yet:

```
public class Test
{
    private static object syncObj = new object();

    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToArray();
        Parallel.ForEach(items, (item, state) =>
        {
            Task2(Task1(item));
        });
    }

    static int Task1(int item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 1 : {0}", item);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        return item;
    }

    static int Task2(int item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 : {0}", item);
        return item;
    }
}
```